# Averaging and adding data in an unknown number of identical rows

Tags: vba, excel, merge, average

I have data that essentially looks like this

`URL       Pageviews   Unique Pageviews   Avg. Time   Entrances   Bounce Rate   %Exit`

`AAA          8               1              1.04        8            0.8         0.6
 AAA          5               3              0.80       10            0.9        0.6 
 AAA         10               5              1.11        8            1           0.6
 AAA          7               2              0.50        4            0.8         0.6 
  BB         12               1              0.37       10            0.75        0.6
  BB          4               2              0.76        3            0.9         0.6`

I want to merge all identical urls into one row and sum the Pageviews/Unique Pageviews / Entrances column data, and average the Avg.Time / Bounce Rate / %Exit columns.

The number of identical rows vary throughout the table.

This is the code I have so far. I'm new to vba and tried to solve this with a two-dimensional array, but got the subscript out of range error.

```
Sub Data()
 Dim Ws As Worksheet
 Dim tbl As ListObject
 Dim lastRow As Long, k As Long, t As Long
 Dim arr() As Long
   Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
   Set tbl = Ws.ListObjects("Table9")

   lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


 For t = 1 To lastRow


 arr(0, 1) = Ws.Cells(t, 2).Value
   Do Until Ws.Cells(t, 1).Value <> Ws.Cells(t + 1, 1).Value
        k = k + 1
        t = t + 1
          ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1, 5) As Long
        arr(k - 1, 5) = Ws.Cells(k - 1, 5).Value

   Loop
       Cells(t - k, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(arr)
       Cells(t - k, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(arr)
       Cells(t - k, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(dataArray)
       Cells(t - k, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(arr)
       Cells(t - k, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(dataArray)
       Cells(t - k, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(dataArray)
       Rows(t - k + 1 & k - 1, 5).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp

       t = t - k
       k = 0

  Next t

  Set tbl = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'd really appreciate any help on this, I've been stuck for a while.

Comment: You can achieve that with a pivot table. Does your solution need to be in VBA?

Comment: Preferably yes, i'm trying to automate a report so everything is done once the data is inputted

Comment: good luck with `undo` when you find a VBA bug... when it's just so straight forward with a pivot table, which can be refreshed at any time and does not overwrite original values :P

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did some research, you're declaring the array okay, but it needs to be re-dimensioned to a multi-dimensional size.

```
Dim arr() As Long
Redim arr(1,1)
```

Comment: The out of range error appears on  
`arr(0, 1) = Ws.Cells(t, 2).Value`
sorry i should've mentioned that

Comment: that makes sense, i'm not sure why though but it gives me an error saying its expecting an expression

Comment: thank you! that worked. now im just getting a mismatch error on `Rows(t - k + 1 & k - 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp`

Comment: Can you explain what that command is supposed to do? I'm not familiar with it yet

Comment: Its supposed to delete all rows with identical urls except for the first one after their data has been combined